# Computed observable not firing despite observable changing

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have the following:

```
sidebarCardVm.showCreateButton = ko.computed(function () {
    return
        (sidebarItemType == "Test") ||
        (sidebarItemType == "Test2" && self.selectedItem() != null); // when selectedItem() changes, I expect this to fire.  It does not.
});
```

I expect a change of `selectedItem` to trigger this:

```
self.selectedItem = ko.computed(function () {
    var matchingCard = getSelectedCard("Item")
    if (matchingCard != null && matchingCard.selectedItem() != null)
        return matchingCard.selectedItem();
    return null;
});
```

But it does not.  I see `self.selectedItem` update, but `showCreateButton` doesn't follow suit.  Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Computeds are very smart in determining their dependencies. For example:

```js
const myObs = ko.observable("Hello world");
const returnEarly = ko.observable(true);

const myComp = ko.computed(
  () => returnEarly() || myObs()
);

console.log(myComp()); // true
console.log(myObs.getSubscriptionsCount()); // 0

returnEarly(false);
console.log(myComp()); // "Hello world"
console.log(myObs.getSubscriptionsCount()); // 1
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
```

Because when `exitEarly` is still `true` the code never reaches the point where it calls `myObs`, no subscription is created. Only once it gets to the second part of the `||`, we'll start triggering updates for new values of `myObs`.

Therefore, this piece of code:

```
(sidebarItemType == "Test") ||
(sidebarItemType == "Test" && self.selectedItem() != null);
```

by definition, can **not** create a subscription to `selectedItem`.

Whenever `sideBarItemType === "Test"`, it will return early and not call `selectedItem`.

Comment: So do I just break my conditions into a bunch of `if` statements with the observable conditions coming first?  It doesn't seem smart if it trains humans to expect a certain behavior and then tricks them in an edge-case.

Comment: Read the statement from your code I highlighted again. If `sidebarItemType` is **not** equal to `"Test"`, the part after `&&` won't be needed to come to the result of `false`: that's the definition of an AND operator. Only when the `a` part in `a && b` is truethy, `b` will be evaluated. Now, since you've *also* included an `||` that checks for `a`, things break: `a || (a && b)` will either return `a` as soon as `a` is truethy, or return `false`. It will *never* return `b`.

Comment: A very important omission was made in my original post.  I am testing against `a || (b & c)` - apologies for the confusion.  Either way, I've broken up my computed into if/else statements to force evaluation of the conditions as a workaround.